# Android 11 document folder zip file access denied

Tags: file, directory, document, android-11

I create one zip file of 50 images in document/face/face.zip path.
but when I try to sent that file path to api  that gives  below 403 forbidden error

<-- 403 Forbidden https://xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxx/admin/xx/xx/xxxx_employee (1657ms)

Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

<-- END HTTP (199-byte body)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: issue is am not able to access .zip file in download directory in android 11

Comment: `code`. val file= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/veritime/register_face.zip")

            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params[ApiParam.EMP_NAME] = binding.etEmpName.text.toString()
            params[ApiParam.EMP_NUMBER] = binding.etEmpNumber.text.toString()
            mViewModel.callRegisterEmpApi(params,file.absolutePath,imagePath)